# ERROR in type.value.visitExpression is not a function

Tags: angular

i recently updated my angular 2 application to angular 9, i followed the steps and corrected every error that the IDE and the command line showed me, but now im stucked, whenever i try to run "ng serve" command i get this message:

[image]

There is no further explanation and there are no errors (at least in intellij)

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.05 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 983 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 153 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 340 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-12-25T15:55:02.318Z - Hash: d98caa034002adb90ffe - Time: 3839ms

ERROR in type.value.visitExpression is not a function
```

Comment: check wheather you have double commas in anywhere in your application module code? check this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2603

Comment: I have them in quite a lot of components, could that be the mistake?

Comment: Yes if you have unwanted commas in module, It will throw these kind of error

Comment: Im checking it and i have no doble commas in none of the app routing, app module and app component. I only got them in some console logs and strings among the whole project

Comment: Can you create stackblitz or share your code ?

Comment: Sure, here is the code:  https://github.com/codeurjc-students/2019-FullTeaching/tree/Angular-Update/src/main/angular

Comment: @Chellappanவ i have found the way of getting more info about the error and it seems to be an error in some types of a library that im using, thank u anyway for answering!

Comment: I tried to run locally i am getting materialize is not know element error. Great  to hear that you found the solution!!